# Retrieving multidimensional json array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I know there are lots of questions and answers on this topic but none that are answering my specific query - I've been searching and going around in circles for a month!

I'm getting values from may database using php and returning via json:

```
    $staff_list = array(
          "name" => $staff_names,
          "id" => $staff_ids,
          "img" => $staff_imgs,
          "typeID" => $staff_types,
    );

    print(json_encode($staff_list));
```

I'm pulling into a javascript:

```
$.getJSON(requestURL, function(data) {
    if( data.errorResponse ) {
            element.html("<p>(" + data.errorResponse.message + ")</p>");
    } else {
        $('#designeesloading').remove();

        $.each(data, function(i, field){
            $.each(field, function(x, value){
                haystack.push({
                  i:value //this should put into 4 arrays as per above shouldn't it?
                });
            });
        });


    } //errorResponse else

  }); //getJSON
```

But instead of haystack now being 25 elements (as there are 25 names, images etc), when I go to extract here, it goes through 100 something times (which I imagine is 4 times x 25):

(this triggers each time someone types in search box):

```
    $.each(haystack, function(i,v) { //this goes through 100 times instead of 25
    if ((v['name'].toLowerCase().indexOf(needle) >= 0)) {
      choices.push({ //only want to add to choices if what they are searching for is found
        "id":v['id'],
        "name":v['name'],
        "typeID":v['typeID'],
        "img":v['img']
      });
      resultflag++;
    }
    });
```

It's here if anyone wants a look.  So frustrating, I'd have this done in 5 minutes in PHP.

http://cybril.com/donation/donate.php

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You're pushing everything into the top level of the `haystack` array, you're not pushing into sub-elements.

Comment: I tried to find the JS code you specified on your website but could not find it.  Can you provide a jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code. First, you're just pushing everything onto `haystack`, you're not creating nested objects to hold each staff member. Second, in an object literal like `{ key: val }`, `i` is not evaluated, it's treated as a literal name; only `val` is evaluated. If you want to use a computed key, you must use square bracket notation.

```
    $.each(data, function(i, field){
        $.each(field, function(x, value){
            if (!haystack[x]) {
                haystack[x] = {};
            }
            haystack[x][i] = value;
        });
    });
```